# nodejs compiling only JS file include CSS. Not compiling separate CSS file

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, nodes

I run this same project on different PC with the same configuration. But it's output is different. The CSS file not compiling on a separate file. Please check these images and how can I get a separate file for CSS. Thanks

[image: compiling properly with separate css.]

compiling properly with separate css.

[image: compiling only js file and CSS converted on this js file]
compiling only js file and CSS converted on this js file

Comment: maybe app.css already exists and checksum is same?

Comment: Yes! CSS exists on the same js file. But I want it in a separate file. I tried by uninstalling and install nodejs. But it's not working.

Comment: then something’s wrong with webpack.config.js. check that file and make a local copy of it and use it as You want